# multiply certain elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays

is there anyway you can multiply certain elements in an array by one number an the others by another?

```
array = [1,2,3,4]
```

is there anyway I can multiply the 1st and 3rd by 2 and the second and fourth by 4 at the same time?
python 2.7 btw

Comment: Is this a NumPy array, or are you using the wrong word for "list"?

Answer (score 1):

Using array of values:

```
>>> array * [2, 4, 2, 4]
array([ 2,  8,  6, 16])
```

And using indexing:

```
>>> array[[0,2]] *= 2
>>> array[[1,3]] *= 4
>>> array
array([ 2,  8,  6, 16])
```